# django admin form - display radio button to control save_model?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.3

In an application adding 'customer' objects the user enters 'shipping' and 'billing' addresses. If the billing address is not added the save does not validate.

I'd like to change this so that user can specify 'Use shipping for billing' via a YES/NO radio button.

How can I get the radio button to display when I don't actually want to save the 'YES'/'NO' value but just make use of it in the save_model method ?

Thanks.

Comment: did you mean to tag this with `django-1.3`

Comment: in your template use html5 radio button and from there you get the value off the button and used that value in the views. but it cannot make sense if you want use in the admin , it should be for costumer options.

Comment: @agconti - yes I'm doing maintenance on a system which is still running on 1.3

Comment: @drabo2005 - unfortunately it is in admin that I need to do this .

Comment: ok, i understand that.